Cloned Dynamic Fields in File Manager Retain Previous Image State: How to Prevent Image Duplication?
Context: I'm trying to create a feature that handles multiple messages and media/files using a file manager. The issue is that while the message part works, the media/files section only reads one file, even after adding code to handle multiple files
the code
<div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTextMedia">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTextMedia" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTextMedia">
                        <?php _e("Text & Media")?>
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapseTextMedia" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTextMedia" data-bs-parent="#campaignAccordion">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                            
                        <label for="type_text_media" class="nav-link bg-active-primary text-gray-700 px-4 py-3 b-r-6 text-active-white <?php _ec( (get_data($result, "type") == 1 || get_data($result, "type") == "")?"active":"" ) ?> hidden-element" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#wa_text_and_media" type="button" role="tab"><?php _e("Test")?></label>
                        <input class="d-none hidden-element" type="radio" name="type" id="type_text_media" <?php _ec( (get_data($result, "type") == 1 || get_data($result, "type") == "")?"checked='true'":"" ) ?> value="1">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-start mb-3">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary me-2" id="add-text-media">
                                    <?php _e("Add Text & Media")?>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-more-text">
                                    <?php _e("Add More Text")?>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div id="dynamic-fields-container">
                                <div class="dynamic-field">
                                    <?php echo view_cell('\Core\Whatsapp\Controllers\Whatsapp::widget_content', ["result" => $result]) ?>
                                    <label class="form-label"><?php _e("Text Message / Caption")?></label>
                                    <?php echo view_cell('\Core\Caption\Controllers\Caption::block', ['name' => 'caption[]', 'value' => get_data($result, "caption")]) ?>
                                    <p class="fs-12 text-danger mb-1">
                                        <span class="paramsDiv"></span>
                                    </p>
                                    <ul class="text-gray-400 fs-12">
                                        <li><?php _e("Random message by Spintax")?></li>
                                        <li><?php _e("Ex: {Hi|Hello|Hola}")?></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="mt-3">
                                <label class="form-label"><?php _e("Send Test Message")?></label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e("Test Recipient Number")?>" id="test-recipient-number">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="send-test-message"><?php _e("Send")?></button>
                                </div>
                                <small class="form-text text-muted"><?php _e("WhatsApp number to receive test message (including country code).")?></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#add-text-media').on('click', function() {
                    const newField = $('.dynamic-field:first').clone(true);
                    newField.find('textarea').val('');
                    newField.find('.emojionearea-editor').text('');
                    addRemoveButton(newField);
                    $('#dynamic-fields-container').append(newField);
                    updateRemoveButtons();
                });

                $('#add-more-text').on('click', function() {
                    const newField = $('.dynamic-field:first').clone(true);
                    newField.find('.fm-selected-media').remove();
                    newField.find('.btnOpenFileManager').remove();
                    newField.find('textarea').val('');
                    newField.find('.emojionearea-editor').text('');
                    addRemoveButton(newField);
                    $('#dynamic-fields-container').append(newField);
                    updateRemoveButtons();
                });

                function addRemoveButton(field) {
                    const removeButton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-hover-scale remove-field mt-2"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <?php _e("Remove") ?></button>');
                    field.append(removeButton);
                }

                $(document).on('click', '.remove-field', function() {
                    $(this).closest('.dynamic-field').remove();
                    updateRemoveButtons();
                });

                function updateRemoveButtons() {
                    const fields = $('.dynamic-field');
                    if (fields.length > 1) {
                        fields.find('.remove-field').show();
                    } else {
                        fields.find('.remove-field').hide();
                    }
                }

                // Initial call to set up remove buttons
                updateRemoveButtons();
            });
            </script>

I added code to support multiple messages and media files in the file manager. The messaging part is working as expected, allowing me to send multiple messages. However, for the media/files section, I was expecting it to allow multiple file uploads, but it currently only reads the first file I upload, even when I try to add more.

I don't see the file manager in your code, I suspect its rendered by this line view_cell('\Core\Whatsapp\Controllers\Whatsapp::widget_content', ["result" => $result]). Could you show the html that function renders and also the controller method that handles the submitted form/file uploads?


 "image,video,doc,pdf,audio,other", "select_multi" => 0]) ?>

here my widget_content

If you want to have a single input allowing multiple file uploads, then you need to grant the attribute of multiple to it. Yet, from your code it seems that you have multiple file uploaders and only the first file is being uploaded.
If that's your problem, then you will need to make sure that the multiple different file uploader inputs have different name attribute values.
Also, if you want to upload files via Javascript, read this article: https://imagekit.io/blog/uploading-multiple-files-using-javascript/
